# How to make implicitly generated TreeViewItem collapse with IValueConverter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I am trying to make implicitly generated TreeViewItems collapse via an IValueConverter.  The code I have removes the grid, but the grid lives in a TreeViewItem.  How can I make that TreeViewItem collapse with an IValueConverter?

```
  <TreeView   Name="TreeViewNew"
                                    Background="Transparent" 
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    >
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MapLayers}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock 
                                            Focusable="False" 
                                            Width="150" 
                                            Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                                            FontSize="10"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            />
                                    </Grid>

                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                             <Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=Layer, Converter={StaticResource cIsDrawingLayer}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the binding you intend to control the TreeViewItem's visiblity in the TreeView's ItemContainerStyle. Probably you will have to repeat that setting in the HierarchicalDataTemplate for each level of TreeViewItems. If a Binding doesn't work, you could still try a Trigger or DataTrigger in the ItemContainerStyle. Probably you wouldn't even need a converter with a Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to accomplish the task:

```
    <TreeView.Resources>   
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" > 
<Setter      Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=Layer,
    Converter={StaticResource cIsDrawingLayer}}" />  
</Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
```